# Automatically listing all Rspec examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Is there any existing tool or command to automatically list every single example in an app?

For example, if I had...

**/spec/apple_spec.rb:**

```
describe Apple do
  it "should be round" do
    @apple.shape.should == "round"
  end
  it "should be red" do
    @apple.colour.should == "red"
  do
end
```

**/spec/banana_spec.rb:**

```
describe Banana do
  it "should be bent" do
    @banana.shape.should == "bent"
  end
  it "should be yellow" do
    @banana.colour.should == "yellow"
  end
end
```

...then the tool or command I'm looking for would yield something like:

```
apple_spec.rb
  - describe apple
    - it should be round
    - it should be red
banana_spec.rb
  - describe banana
    - it should be bent
    - it should be yellow
```

Reviewing this output would help me to confirm that I'd tested all the behaviours that were important to me.

Comment: Doesn't the default RSpec output basically do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `format=documentation` will produce nicely formatted output for all examples, passing and failing. You can do this on the command line:

`rspec --format=documentation`

Or add the setting to the `.rspec` config file in the root of your project.